# Get sizeof a void (*)() function pointer in C

Tags: c

To aid with some precise memory allocation that I'm doing in `C`, I'm trying to get the `sizeof` a function pointer for a function with return type void that takes no parameters.

However, when I do `sizeof (void (*)())`, I generate a compiler warning:

`function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]`

How do I get the size that I'm looking for?

Comment: `sizeof(function pointer)` gives you size of a pointer.
Function pointer is also a pointer. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Gopi: true on POSIX, false in general. The standard doesn't even require that a function pointer can safely do a roundtrip through a `void *`.

Comment: Incidentally, you could just do `sizeof(&memcpy)` or some other standard function from headers you already include. Or, if you are trying to get the size for some variable, you could just do `sizeof` on it.

Comment: That's a bogus warning. You should ignore it. Yes, `void()` is a K&R declaration but that's neither wrong nor something the compiler should warn about. In fact, it's common to have function pointer point to prototype-less function as that reduces the number of casts you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is an old style function definition, it is missing the argument list, so add them:

```
sizeof( void(*)(void) )
```

Answer (score 2):

For readability purposes, I recommend declaring a type for the *signature* of any function you'll want have some pointer to:

```
 typedef void my_sigt(void);
```

then, to declare a pointer to such a function, code:

```
 my_sigt* funptr;
```

and to get its size code `sizeof(my_sigt*)` (or `sizeof(funptr)` if you have such a variable `funptr`)

BTW, I am not sure that the C99 standard guarantees that every function pointer has the same size (or has the same size as some data pointer). But POSIX requires that (in particular, to be able to use [dlsym](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) for dynamic linking of such functions).